# PHP search engine for text files with indexing

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I have some text files inside a directory (and its sub directories). The number of text files will be (50000+) and the directory is outside 'public_html':

```
text_root_dir
|-- |-- `001
           |-- text0003.txt
           |-- text0004.txt
           |-- text0005.txt
           |-- `001_a
                   |-- text0006.txt
                   |-- text0007.txt
                   |-- text0008.txt
    |-- text0001.txt
    |-- text0002.txt
```

The text file details are saved in a MySQL table (with the '*art_textfile*' storing the text file name and '*art_path*' column storing the file path):

```
CREATE TABLE `stxt_articles` (
  `art_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `art_title` VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  `art_author`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `art_textfile`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, /* TEXT FILE NAME */
  `art_path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, /* TEXT FILE PATH */
    PRIMARY KEY(`art_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I am using PHP/MySQL (LAMP) and want to do a string search on the text files (with regular expressions if possible). The methods that will work logically are:

1. Storing the contents in the MySQL database and perform a search with MySQL query (LIKE 's%')
2. Scan the directory by PHP and search within each text file for a search expression.

But with a large dataset of 5000 +files (tend to grow over time), the above options are not practical. It will be too slow to use.

What I am looking for is a PHP/MySQL search idea which creates index for text files and do a search. Pretty much what Lucene does in JAVA. Maybe I can refer it as a lucene alternative in PHP with MySQL.

Thanks for reading this far. Also thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: MySQL does not support indexes for regular expression matches. The indexes can only be used for exact or "starts with" matches (e.g. `LIKE "text%"`), but not for ends with or contains matches (percent wildcard character anywhere but the end of the string). RLIKE and other regular expression functions will not use the indexes.

Comment: Zend Framework has a Lucene implementation (Lucene is a specification, it’s not JAVA specific but the reference implementation happens to be made with JAVA). It works well but doesn’t perform well under heavy load. I recommend looking into an Elasticsearch solution that you can integrate with. I say this as someone with *lot* of experience with Zend Lucene and Elasticsearch. Home brew solutions like string matching in the DB are never going to compare to a mature, full featured search engine.

Comment: Bus Elasticsearch is not free. Any other PHP/MySQL based application to create index and search?

Comment: @Jim - Rephrase to "an INDEX won't be used if the LIKE expression starts with a wild card".  For example"  `LIKE 'ch%t%'` can use an index.

Comment: How big are the text files?

Comment: @RickJames - You are partially right. It will use the index for anything that starts with "ch" but then will have to loop and filter for anything containing a t after that. What I was referring to was `LIKE "%something"` or `LIKE "%some%thing%"`

Comment: @RickJames - Ranging from few bytes to upto 10MB max

Comment: As I have studied and discussed on the matter for last couple of days, it seems it is practically impossible to do it in PHP/MySQL when execution time is concerned.  So I am considering to use SOLR for the purpose.

Comment: @sariDon - If you implement it in SOLR, please post your results here.

Comment: Sure @RickJames. I will use Django with SOLR

Answer (score 0):

Using something like AJAX seems to be pretty fast, I'm sorry if I misunderstood your post. (Code will need tweaks for doing exactly what you want but should be a good starting point)

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("search").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("search").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("search").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="search"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

search.php

```php
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$files = scandir("FOLDER")
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  $directory = 'Directory';
  $results_array = array();

  if (is_dir($directory)) {
  if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE) {
      $results_array[] = $file;
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
}


foreach($results_array as $value) {
  if(str_starts_with($value, $q)){
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the option#2 I suggested (Scan the directory by PHP and search within each text file for a search expression). But this will take a lot of time for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

50000 file opens, alone, would take a long time.  That does not include the time to search the text in each.

Load the data into a MySQL table with ENGINE=InnoDB (not the deprecated MyISAM).  Then you can do very fast queries that are "word oriented" -- this is meeting FULLTEXT's limitation.

You *can* also do `LIKEs` (slow) or `REGEXPs` (even slower).

What I do in such situations is allow the user to use either LIKE syntax or REGEXP syntax or simple word(s).  Add `FULLTEXT(txt)` (assuming `txt` contains all the text you need to search).  Then my code goes something like:

If it looks like "word(s)" of at least 3 letters, stick a '+' in front of each word and build `MATCH(txt) AGAINST ("+John +Doe" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.  In most situations it will be very fast.

Else, if I see %, then I build a `LIKE` expression and assume the user knows `LIKE` syntax.

Else, if I assume it is a regexp and go down that path.

It's imperfect, but it covers a lot of bases.

If the users understand that "words" are faster, they will gravitate that way.